# Is it good to override React state array this way?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Please this is not a duplicate question. My question is about will it cause a bug if I assign a state array to a local variable and push values to a local variable.

I got into a situation to understand which is right when pushing values into React state array or overriding the values.

As per React documentation the below code is a bad style and causes a bug

```
   this.state = {
        list: []
  }

  componentDidMount(){
      const { list } = this.state;
      list.push(“test”);//this is bad style of pushing values into React state and causes a bug
      this.setState({list});
 }
```

What if I do like below, will it causes a bug? Assigning state list to a local variable and pushing values to that local variable and setting state of array to list. is this same as above code?

```
  this.state = {
        list: []
  }
  componentDidMount(){
      const { list } = this.state;
      const array = list;
      array.push(“test”); //pushing values to a local variable  too a bad style and causes a bug in React?
      this.setState({list: array});
 }
```

Comment: You are doing almost the same thing. `list` and `array` points to same array object. So `this.setState({list: array});` line is redundant

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, your second approach will also cause bug, because the state array gets updated at this stage { array.push(“test”); }. And if your class is PureComponent then it will not re-render.

So you can try this

```
 const list = [... this.state.list];
```

OR

```
 const list = this.state.list.slice();
```

This way it creates a copy of array.

Your new code will look like below :-

```
const list = [... this.state.list];
list.push("new value");
this.setState({ list });
```

Comment: You mean const list = [...this.state.list]; and list.push(“test”); won’t causes a bug?

Comment: Yes, it won't cause bug.

Answer (score 3):

Your first example is not really a React bug, I'm not sure it can be considered a bug at all. `Array.prototype.push()` mutates the array and that's something you want to avoid with React (To not modify state directly).

Obviously you can do something similar like you did in your second example by using `Array.prototype.slice()`

```
let newList = this.state.list.slice();
newList.push(someValue);

this.setState({ list: newList })
```

Another alternative would be simply to use `Array.prototype.concat()` direclty in your `setState()`

```
this.setState({ list: this.state.list.concat(someValue)})
```

I guess this are the options coming in my mind right now.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a bug but expected behaviour. State shouldn't be mutated.

Two snippets in the questions are identical, arrays are objects and objects are passed by reference in JavaScript, so it doesn't matter whether it's `list` or `array` that is mutated.

`list` array should be immutable, i.e. if it needs to be changed, a new array is created.

Also, using `this.state` values in `this.setState` is [antipattern](http://setState()%20does%20not%20always%20immediately%20update%20the%20component.%20It%20may%20batch%20or%20defer%20the%20update%20until%20later.%20This%20makes%20reading%20this.state%20right%20after%20calling%20setState()%20a%20potential%20pitfall.%20Instead,%20use%20componentDidUpdate%20or%20a%20setState%20callback%20(setState(updater,%20callback)),%20either%20of%20which%20are%20guaranteed%20to%20fire%20after%20the%20update%20has%20been%20applied.%20If%20you%20need%20to%20set%20the%20state%20based%20on%20the%20previous%20state,%20read%20about%20the%20updater%20argument%20below.):

> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state right after calling setState() a potential pitfall. Instead, use componentDidUpdate or a setState callback (setState(updater, callback)), either of which are guaranteed to fire after the update has been applied. If you need to set the state based on the previous state, read about the updater argument below.

Updater function should be used instead:

```
componentDidMount(){
  this.setState(({ list }) => ({ list: [...list, 'test'] }));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
this.setState({ list:[..this.state.list,'new value'] });
```

you can use spread operator directly to setState .. hope it will work